# this function run too many times

Tags: c

Why if I write some other letter or number(not y\n) the order

```
printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):");
```

run twice?

```
int ans= 0,i=1;
do
{
    printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):");
    ans = getchar();
    if (ans=='y')
    {
        printf("yyyyyyyyyyy");
        i = i-1;
    }
    else if ( ans == 'n')
    {
        printf("nnnnnnnnnnn");
        i=i-1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not y or n");
    }
}
while(i);
```

Comment: You should delete your question only if it is poorly posed. You should not delete it just because you got the answer to your problem. Remember that SO is a repository of questions and answers. Your question and the posted answers might be useful to someone else in the future. You should undo the last edit and restore the question.

Comment: If you got your answer, you should accept it. This is the stackoverflow way to say "thank you for your time". To get comfortable, please take the [tour].

Comment: You could try something like [This](http://ideone.com/QQg72K)

Comment: @Michi: Why simple if you can make it complicated?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, you right. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `while(i)` is effectively the same as `while(i != 0)`.  If you enter something other than `y` or `n`, the `else` block runs, and does not change the value of `i`.  Since `i=1` before the loop, `i` is nonzero if you enter something other than `y` or `n`.  Try:

```
else
{
    printf("not y or n");
    i = i-1;   // <---- new line
}
```

Comment: it's work but i want it to say over and over "Would you like to play again? " when you put something that not y or n.

Comment: @cxw How about [if the input is](http://pastebin.com/raw/wev3U2F5) `1234567` ? [Demo](http://ideone.com/WHF9fn)

Comment: @Michi the original code will run once for each character of the input.  If you have questions about other code, would you please ask a separate question?  Post the link and I'll take a look next time I'm on.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because your `getchar` call is picking up the newline from your input. So if you press 'X', the first time through the loop `ans` is 'X' and the newline was buffered. The second time through the loop `ans` is '\n'.

You can put a loop around your input call like this:

```
do
    ans = getchar();
while (isspace(ans));
```

Comment: I need to do it without functions

Comment: Well then you can do the check for ans being a whitespace character manually. All you really care about is \n in this case anyway.

Comment: You cannot write any useful code in C without functions, since you need them for output (as you have done).

Answer (score 2):

This is overcomplicated. As you stated in a comment, you just want to loop until `y` or `no` has been typed. No need for an extra variable. In general for such problems it is a bad idea to use a counter. More failsafe is using a `bool` flag.

A good approach without helper variable would be:

```
int ans;    // no need to initialise, as it is set before the first read
do {
    printf("Play again?");
    do {
        ans = getchar();
    } while ( ans == `\n` );
    ...
} while ( (ans != EOF) && !strchr("yYnN", ans) );
```

See [`strchr`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.5.2). I added tolerance for uppercase letters.

Note that you always check for EOF, too. As that cannot be represented as a `char`, you have to test seperately and **first** (otherwise the conversion in `strchr` might yield unexpected results.

Also note `fflush`ing an input stream (which can be found in some code on the internet) is undefined behaviour - don't use it. Even if some libraries tolerate it, they might not behave as expected (which is implied by *undefined behaviour*). Flushing in general as the semantics of "writing/sending out" data. Input normally is "dropped" (and there is no`fdrop` function.

**Edit:** Added inner loop to drop newline characters. Without that the loop will run twice after an invalid character entered. This assumes you have to enter one character per line.

Comment: Nice use of `strchr()`.

Comment: @Erobrere: I did not even mention `scanf`. Why would I? [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). If you need one liter of water you do not use a full-size barrel. If you want to promote `scanf`, please provide your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what letter you type before you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the line

```
c = getchar();
```

still leaves the newline character in the input stream.

If the character is something other than `y` and `n`, that call gets executed without waiting for you and the newline character gets assigned to `c`. Hence, you see output from the following lines twice.

```
printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):");
```

and

```
printf("not y or n");
```

You need to add code to ignore the rest of the line from the input after

```
c = getchar();
```

Add a function:

```
void ignoreRestOfLine()
{
   int c;
   while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

and call it as:

```
c = getchar();
ignoreRestOfLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that when you go into the program again in the do while there is already an answer in memory. `getchar()` adds a \n and that is what stays. to avoid this you can make ans a character (char) meaning that it will be reading the ascii table; (y = 121 and n = 110). Char does not place a \n (new line) after it receives the input, to make sure this happens you have to leave a space before %c like so `scanf(" %c", &ans);` this means that ans is receiving a int.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    char ans;
    int i = 1;
    do
    {
        printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y/n):");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);
        if (ans == 121){
            printf("yyyyyyyyyyy");
            i = i - 1;
        }
        else if ( ans == 110){
            printf("nnnnnnnnnnn");
            i = i - 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("not y or n");
        }
    }
    while(i);
}
```

Comment: `main` should be at least `int main(void){}` Any way you should [Fix this](http://pastebin.com/raw/eMMb4FvZ)

Comment: sorry I was just making a snippet to run the code. Forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
char c = 'x'; // Initialize to a character other than input
while( c != 'y' || c != 'n') { // You can also use strchr as @Olaf mentioned
    printf ("\nPlay again (y/n): ");
    c = getchar ();
}
```