# fgets() not working properly

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I am writing a simple code where I need to input a number n, followed by n strings in the format "string int" (eg. hello 100). I have used `fgets()` function to take the string input. The code seems to be working fine for all iterations except the first one. The first iteration seems to have an empty input for cmd, but the rest of the iterations runs fine. I've tried various functions like `scanf()` and `gets()`, but the problem remains. Can anyone please point out the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int num_msg, i;
    printf("Hello, How many strings should I read?: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_msg);

    for (i = 0; i < num_msg; i++) {
        int child;
        char cmd[100], msg[100];
        printf("Message %d (<msg> <int>):", i + 1);

        if (fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin)) {
            //printf("cmd %s\n", cmd);
            sscanf(cmd, "%s %d %*s", msg, &child);  //separates string and int
            printf("%s %d \n", msg, child);  //prints them
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use **scanf("%d\n"…** to remove it ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34498302/434551 for a function to ignore the rest of the line.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I did that and it now takes the input, but the input is taken before the print statement in the loop.

Comment: @ArifBurhan, use of `"%d\n"` or `"%d "` will consume not only the newline but also any whitespace characters in the next line too. It's too greedy.

Comment: @RSahu I always use **gets()** followed by **sscanf()**

Comment: @RSahu the ignore rest of the line worked!! Many Thanks!

Comment: @ArifBurhan, Did you mean `fgets()`? If not, you should change your coding habits.

Comment: Not testing the return value of *scanf functions is always asking for a surprise.

Comment: @Jens yes, it is. I still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consume the `\n` that follows the number read by `scanf()`.

Adding a `\n` at the end of the `scanf()` format is not appropriate, since it would consume all whitespace characters and keep requesting input until a non space character in input.

A quick and dirty way to do this is to replace the `scanf` with:

```
scanf("%d%*c", &num_msg);
```

The `%*c` reads a single character and does not store it.

You could also store it into a `char` variable and verify that it is indeed a `'\n'`.

A generic way to ignore all characters upto and including the linefeed:

```
scanf("%d", &num_msg);
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    continue;
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` to verify that a number was correctly converted.

Comment: It worked!
Thank you very much!
I knew the problem had something to do with the newline in scanf() function, so I used scanf("%d\n") which accepted the input but messed up with the print sequence. %*c works perfectly!

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to do that.
Thanks again!